# Dynamic binding of html pages with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs and need to do some stuff using angularjs. So my question is just to add some separate html pages to one page by using angular controller. Though I do not know how to do this and search it as well help would be appreciated.

I have a html page like this.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div1" >
  </div>

  <div id="div2" >
  </div>

  <div id="div3" >   
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And again I have 3 separate html pages ie. html1 , html2 , html3 likewise. So now I need to put my 3 html pages in to above html page dynamically by using angularjs. Help would bbe really appreciated.

Comment: `ng-include` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Did you do the AngularJS Phonecat tutorial?

Comment: not yet. But I hope to study them. But I have no time for tutorials for this one. I just have few hours. That is why I asked from you guys about this. :(

Comment: @callmekatootie Can you give me the link for that tutorial? I searched but couldn't find it.

Comment: [Phonecat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `ng-include`.

```
<html>
<body ngApp>
  <div ng-include="firstPage.html"/>
  <div ng-include="secondPage.html"/>
  <div ng-include="thirdPage.html"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to include and apply scope dynamically, you need `$templateCache` and `$compile`.